# jQuery Ajax send to the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I want to figure out how jQuery Ajax work when I don't define url for it. So it should send the data to the same page where is the ajax also. How can I get for example the 'GET' data after the ajax has been completed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".idoszak").change(function() {
        var idoszak=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'idoszak='+ idoszak;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", // or POST
            url: "statisztika.php", //The page where is also this script
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                ???
            } 
        });

    });
});
```

Now the php:

```
    <select name="idoszak" class="idoszak">
        <option value="felev">Félév</option>
        <option value="evvege">Évvége</option>
      </select>
<div id="statisztika">
.
.
.
<?
        $katlag = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT jegy FROM jegyek WHERE `jegyek`.`osztaly` = '$osztaly' AND `jegyek`.`piros` = '0' AND datum = '$idoszak'");
                $katlagok = mysqli_num_rows($katlag);
?>
.
.
.
</div>
```

Comment: Not able to understand the issue here. Can you elaborate? If `load` is the problem, try `$('#statisztika').html(html)`

Comment: The problem is that I want to refresh the mysqli_queries in the #statisztika div without page refreshing, and for that I want a select change event which put the value of the select to a variable and then the mysqli_queries run for the correct (select value) date because in the mysqli_ queries I have "...WHERE date = '$variable'..."

Comment: What is the url of php file? your ajax should have url parameter  `url: 'your_file_name.php?'+datastring`

Comment: No, because if I don't have 'url:' for ajax, it should send the datas for the current page, I have problems to get this data in real time because If I define $idoszak = $_GET['idoszak']; the ajax run but $idoszak doesn't have value so the queries run without it.

Comment: `val()` should work. Post markup of your select.

Comment: You don't understand correctly, everything is cool except the getting of the data, If I make a page for ajax forexample "url: statisztika2.php,' and then in the succes I say "$('#statisztika').html(html);" then it will load the post variable into the #statisztika. But I don't want another page for this and I want to load the select value to a variable.

Comment: Edited the post for better understanding for my problem

Comment: "I want to load the select value to a variable" — A PHP variable or a JavaScript variable? Where do you want to *use* that variable? How can you tell it isn't being put in a variable already (there's no sign of you trying to use anything from the response in your code)?

Comment: URL is the only mandatory parameter for an ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Otherwise, it's like you take your phone and you speak in it without dialing anyone. Ajax won't call "the same page", because "the same page" is in your browser and Ajax is meant to call a server-side resource. Your phone won't call itself if you don't dial anyone.

Comment: I want that $idoszak contains $_GET['idoszak'] after the ajax excecuted, because in a div I have mysqli_query and $idoszak need for the right query.

Comment: @MátéLóczi — That's a PHP variable but there isn't any PHP code in your question. What makes you think it doesn't have the right value? What are you doing to look?

Comment: @Quentin
I edited the question now you can see how I need the variable.

Comment: @MátéLóczi — You're missing `$idoszak  = $_GET['idoszak']`. The problem seems kinda obvious.

Comment: Yes, this should work, but not. I put  $idoszak = $_GET['idoszak']; before #statisztika, run it and it's not working,I think because Ajax opens the page, run it but not the page what is opened, so there is no $_GET data on the current page.

Comment: Why would there be `$_GET` data on the *current* page? That's a different page to the one you just requested with Ajax.

Comment: no, it's the same page, this is the problem, I don't want another page for this because It's just a variable. Now I have a solution but not perfect, if I make a new page, for example sql.php with "session_start();
$_SESSION['idoszak'] = $_POST['idoszak'];" and then call $_SESSION['idoszak'] on the main page it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is happening:

1. You type a URL into the address bar (or follow a link or something like that)
2. Your browser makes a request to that URL
3. The server sends a response back to the browser
4. The browser renders the page
5. You trigger some JavaScript
6. The JavaScript gets the browser to make an Ajax request to the same URL (well, almost the same URL: you've changed the query string)
7. The server sends a response back to the browser
8. The browser makes the response available to JavaScript

You appear to be expecting step 8 to be *the browser replaces the page rendered at step 4 with one based on the data from step 7*. That doesn't happen.

All that happens is that the response is made available to JavaScript.

The body of that response will be in the `html` variable of the success function.

If you want to change what the user is seeing in the page, then you will have to write JavaScript to manipulate the DOM of the page (which can use the data from the `html` variable).